# testing array and function mocha javascript - how to get access to function and write tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I have this code to write test in `index.js` file:

```
'use strict'
const activeModules = [
    { name: 'module 1' },
    { name: 'module 2' },
    { name: 'module 11' },
    { name: 'module 3' },
    { name: 'module 10' }
];
const getCustomModuleNumber = _ =>
    Math.max(...activeModules.map( n =>
        n.name.match("\\d+")
    ));
```

I want to write test in mocha chai but I don't know how I can have access to function in `test/appTest.js`

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;

const app = require('../index');

activeModulesResult = app.activeModules;
getCustomModuleNumberResult = app.getCustomModuleNumber;

describe('App', function() {
    it('activeModules should be type array', function() {
        assert.typeOf(activeModulesResult, 'array');
    });

    it('getCustomModuleNumber should be type number', function() {
        assert.typeOf(getCustomModuleNumberResult, 'number');
    });
})
```

The console shows the error with `getCustomModuleNumber is undefined` or when I add `getCustomModuleNumber()` shows that is not a function.

**1.** My project contains only `index.js` file and files needed for testing. What is the best way to test this and why? Maybe i need to add to `index.js` file `module.exports`? which solution will be the most optimal and consistent with the principles of clean code and ES6?

**2.** What tests should I write?  I know I should check if the `getCustomModuleNumber` function returns `11`, the `type` returned by it, but I completely do not know if I should check also the other components of this function?

EDIT:

i've written such tests:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const app = require('../index').main;

activeModulesResult = app.activeModules;
getCustomModuleNumberResult = app.getCustomModuleNumber();
describe('App', function() {
    describe('activeModules', function(){
        it('activeModules should be type array', function() {
            assert.isArray(activeModulesResult);
        });
        it('activeModules has the same members', function() {
            const testArray = [
                { name: 'module 1' },
                { name: 'module 2' },
                { name: 'module 11' },
                { name: 'module 3' },
                { name: 'module 10' },
            ];
            assert.includeDeepMembers(activeModulesResult, testArray , 'same members');
        });
    });
    describe('getCustomModuleNumber', function(){
        it('getCustomModuleNumber should be type number', function() {
            assert.isNumber(getCustomModuleNumberResult);
        });
        it('getCustomModuleNumber should return 11', function() {
            assert.equal(getCustomModuleNumberResult, 11);
        });
    });
})
```

Is it ok and is that all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to export the objects -

```
'use strict'
exports.activeModules = [
    { name: 'module 1' },
    { name: 'module 2' },
    { name: 'module 11' },
    { name: 'module 3' },
    { name: 'module 10' }
];
exports.getCustomModuleNumber = () => Math.max(
    ...activeModules.map( n => n.name.match("\\d+"))
);
```

Secondly, if all your function does is matching the module number using `regex` then I guess just checking the respective values you know will be returned should enough.